# Geometry Nodes - Image Texturing doesn't extrude in normal vector

Tags: texturing, uv, geometry-nodes, displacement

i want to do image texturing using geometry nodes, because i want to combine it with other nodes.

The Image Texture node (second picture) doesn't produce a texture in normal direction. Does anyone know how to make texture like first picture using geometry nodes?

Thanks! :D

[image: Texture from Displace Modifier]
Texture using displacement modifier

[image: Texture from Geometry Nodes]
Texture using geometry nodes "image texture"

Comment: You've plugged a UV map into the image texture... a UV map is a 2-dimensional map usually arranging the faces' X and Y dimensions. The normal of a face is pointing outwards of the face in the third dimension, not a vector that the UV map provides.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to displace the mesh in normal direction, you need to provide the normal information in the nodetree. You can simply do this by adding a *Normal* node and plugging it into the *Offset* of the *Set Position* node. Immediately all vertices are moved outwards by 1 in normal direction.

To control how far they are moved outwards, you can scale the normals by using a *Vector Math* node set to *Scale*. And to influence the displacement by the image texture, you plug this into the *Scale* input. Use a *Map Range*, *Color Ramp* or *Multiply* node to increase or decrease the strength of the texture (I didn't use the UV Map for the texture because I didn't unwrap the object):

[image: displaced along normal]

Answer (score 0):

Further to [@Gordon's answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/287802/35559).. you may want your displacement to be mapped in UV space (rather than the default *Position*, or Object space). But his point that the (Float) texture should scale (Vector) *Normal*, if you want the displacement to be along normals, remains the same.

[image]

At the moment you are casting what looks like a Float texture value `v` to a Vector 'Offset' . That will result in a displacement of `(v,v,v)` as on the left:

[image]

as opposed to a displacement  of `v*N`, on the right.